# Can I use GetDataRow() on a view if the view's datasource is IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, drag-and-drop, devexpress

I am implementing drag and drop functionality in a form and I'm running into a situation where I need to GetDataRow, but the view has been bound to an IQueryable, as such:

```
    private void stackOverFlow()
    {
        Func<int, IQueryable> query = i =>
                                      from p in _data.PERSON
                                      where p.FavoriteNumber == i
                                      select p;

        gc1.DataSource = query(17);

        var row = ((GridView) gc1.DefaultView).GetDataRow(0);
    }
```

The row is always null due to the nature of the binding... Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetDataRow() method is designed to return a DataRow object.  This method can be used when the GridContol is bound to a DataView or DataTable object.  In your case, I would suggest that you use the View's GetRow() method, it will return a PERSON object in your case.

Comment: In short, the answer to my question is no, I require a DataView or Table.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
gc1.DataSource = query(17).ToList();
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197106/binding-gridview-to-iqueryablet/5197195#5197195).

Comment: this is true, but cannot resolve my issue, I need to convert the query to a DataTable.