# Convert dynamic query result to a list in order to bind to a grid

Tags: linq-to-entities, dynamic-linq

I am using the following query in vb.net using the System.Linq.Dynamic library to bind the result to a gridview

```
Dim customers = model.Customers _
    .OrderBy(sortExp + " " + sortOrder) _
    .Select("new (CustomerID, CompanyName, ContactName, ContactTitle, Address, City,     Region, PostalCode, Country, Phone, Fax)")

grdCustomers.DataSource = customers
grdCustomers.DataBind()
```

The following error is displayed

**Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported. 
Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, 
and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. 
For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList().**

The result returned is of type DbQuery but I cannot do a ToList() on the result.

There must be a cleaner way to create a list instead of interating through the customers and creating the list manually.

Comment: what you use? webforms, winforms,wpf or something else?

Comment: I am using webforms, vs2012

Comment: you can try `grdCustomers.DataSource = list.Cast<dynamic>().AsEnumerable();` also it seems on this question [binding-gridview-to-iqueryablet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197106/binding-gridview-to-iqueryablet), because DymanicLinq query return `IQueryable`

Comment: I tried grdCustomers.DataSource = customers.Cast(Of DynamicClass).AsQueryable() and grdCustomers.DataSource = customers.Cast(Of Employee).AsQueryable() but still get the same error.  Also note I have changed a mistake in the question.  Datasource is assigned customers variable and not the list variable.  When I check the value of customers in watch window the result is of type System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery(Of System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable).  Basically I want a typed list of employees.

Comment: in my sample `AsEnumerable()` why you try `AsQueryable()`? :-)

Comment: try `grdCustomers.DataSource = list.Cast(Of dynamic)().AsEnumerable();`

Comment: I tried  grdCustomers.DataSource = list.Cast(Of DynamicClass)().AsEnumerable() and got the same error.  in vb.net I am not getting (Of dynamic) in intellisense therefore I am using DynamicClass.

Comment: try `Cast(Of Object)`

Comment: also tried this but I get the same error.  further reading on the web suggests that it is not possible to convert the result of a query from dynamic linq to a List type when working with Linq to Entities.  It is only possible to do this if the data is coming from Linq to Sql.  There is LINQKit which will do the job of system.linq.dynamic library.